# vb.net Task(Of HttpResponseMessage) to HttpResponseMessage

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net async httpResponse function like this:

```
Public Async Function getWebserviceResponse(ByVal sb As StringBuilder, ByVal baseUri As Uri, ByVal Method As String, ByVal User As String, ByVal Password As String) As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)

    Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
    client.BaseAddress = baseUri

    Dim authHeader As AuthenticationHeaderValue = New AuthenticationHeaderValue(
        "Basic",
        Convert.ToBase64String(
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                String.Format("{0}:{1}", User, Password))))

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authHeader

    Dim content As New StringContent(sb.ToString, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")

    Dim resp As HttpResponseMessage
    Dim cancellationToken As CancellationToken

    If Method = "Post" Then
        resp = Await client.PostAsync(baseUri, content, cancellationToken)

    ElseIf Method = "Put" Then
        resp = Await client.PutAsync(baseUri, content, cancellationToken)

    End If

    Return resp

End Function
```

The problem is, that "resp" should return a "normal" HttpResponseMessage and not a Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)...

How can I get this? Thank you in advance for your help!

Best regards
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resp` *is* an `HttpResponseMessage`.  However, the method is `Async`.  Note the method signature:

```
Public Async Function getWebserviceResponse(...) As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)
```

So while the code is logically returning an `HttpResponseMessage`, the method *technically* returns a `Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)`.  This works exactly the same as the methods being invoked therein.  Note here:

```
resp = Await client.PostAsync(baseUri, content, cancellationToken)
```

The `PostAsync` method returns a `Task(Of HttpResponseMessage)`, but that line of code is putting an `HttpResponseMessage` into the `resp` variable.  This is because of the use of the `Await` keyword.

To achieve the same behavior, any method which invokes your `getWebserviceResponse()` method should do the same:

```
someVariable = Await getWebServiceResponse(...)
```

---

**Edit:** Based on your comment below, you have this line of code:

```
Dim myStreamReader As New StreamReader(webserviceResponse.getWebserviceResponse(....).Content.ReadAsStream‌​Async().Result)
```

Which I suspect should be changed to this to use the `Await` keyword:

```
Dim myStreamReader As New StreamReader(Await (Await webserviceResponse.getWebserviceResponse(....)).Content.ReadAsStream‌​Async())
```

Or, to break it up into something a little less confusing:

```
Dim responseMessage As HttpResponseMessage = Await webserviceResponse.getWebserviceResponse(....)
Dim responseStream As Stream = Await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()
Dim myStreamReader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
```

Each individual async operation would need to be awaited.

Comment: Thank you very much David! I will check the solution this evening.

Comment: If I want to invoke my getWebserviceResponse() with a StreamReader I get still the following error: "Content" is not a member of "System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage)".

I know, the await ist missing in the statement: 
Dim myStreamReader As New StreamReader(webserviceResponse.getWebserviceResponse(....).Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)

How can I improve the invoke statement with await? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @Martin: That's because Content isn't a property of a Task.  You have to *await* the task, as suggested in the answer.  Also, it's best not to use "Result", but to await the result.

Comment: @Martin: I've updated the answer to address the line of code in your comment.

Comment: Thank you - the request works now properly!
Great help :-) Have a nice weekend and best regards, Martin